# Confirmation message after inserted data in new page

Tags: javascript, php

Good day all, I'm new to PHP and I really need some help. I'm trying to make a confirmation message in new page after inserting data. I tried echo and print the results, But nothing work to me!!!!.  This is the only problem I faced which I could not solved !!!

Code for **request.php** page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body dir="rtl">
    <div class="container" style="width:400px;">
        <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="formcontroller">
            <form name="userForm" id="contact" ng-submit="insertData()">
                <label class="text-success" ng-show="successInsert">{{successInsert}}</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>name<span class="text-danger"></span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="insert.name" class="form-control" /><span class="text-danger" ng-show="errorname">{{errorname}}</span>
                </div>
                <fieldset class="frmain">
                    <label>contact</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="em" ng-model="insert.em" class="form-control" placeholder="اemail" />
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="errorem">{{errorem}}</span>
                        <input type="text" name="telph" ng-model="insert.telph" class="form-control" placeholder="mobile" />
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="errortelph">{{errortelph}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>department<span class="text-danger"></span>
                        </label>
                        <select ng-model="insert.dept" name="dept" class="form-control" style="font-family: times new roman;font-size: 18px;" />
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="accounting department" </option>
                            <option value="huamn resources"></option>
                            <option value="IT department"></option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="text-danger" ng-show="errordept">{{errordept}}</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="width: 320px;">
                        <label>details<span class="text-danger"></span>
                        </label>
                        <textarea name="det" ng-model="insert.det" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="errordet">{{errordet}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button name="submit" type="submit">send</button>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

<script>
    var application = angular.module("myapp", []);
    application.controller("formcontroller", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.insert = {};
        $scope.insertData = function() {
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "req_add.php",
                data: $scope.insert,
            }).success(function(data) {
                if (data.error) {
                    $scope.errorname = data.error.name;
                    $scope.errorem = data.error.em;
                    $scope.errortelph = data.error.telph;
                    $scope.errordept = data.error.dept;
                    $scope.errordet = data.error.det;
                    $scope.successInsert = null;
                } else {
                    $scope.insert = null;
                    $scope.errorname = null;
                    $scope.errorem = null;
                    $scope.errortelph = null;
                    $scope.errordept = null;
                    $scope.errordet = null;
                    $scope.successInsert = data.message;
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Code for **req_add.php** page: (to insert data into DB)

```
<?php
//req_add.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$form_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
mysqli_query($connect,'set names utf8') or die (mysqli_error($connect));
$data = array();
$error = array();
$date1 = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');// 2017-07-12 10:35:45
 $today = date("Ymd");
$rand = strtoupper(substr(uniqid(sha1(time())),0,4));
$no1 = $today . $rand;  


if(empty($form_data->name))
{
 $error["name"] = "name is required";
}
if(empty($form_data->em))
{
 $error["em"] = "email is required";
}
if(empty($form_data->telph))
{
 $error["telph"] = "mobile number is required";
}
if(empty($form_data->dept))
{
 $error["dept"] = "department is required";
}
if(empty($form_data->det))
{
 $error["det"] = "details are required";
}
if(!empty($error))
{
 $data["error"] = $error;
}
else
{

      $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $form_data->name);
      $em = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $form_data->em);  
      $telph = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $form_data->telph);  
      $dept = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $form_data->dept);  
      $det = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $form_data->det);
      $no = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $form_data->no1);
     $reqdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $form_data->reqdate);
     $answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $form_data->answer);

$query = "INSERT INTO requests(name, em, telph, dept, det, no, reqdate, answer) VALUES ('$name','$em', '$telph', '$dept', '$det', '$no1', '$date1', 'no answer')"; 

 if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
 {
 $data["message"] = "thank you for your request, your request nymber is: " .$no1;
 }
} 
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Look into [toast/snackbar messages](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_snackbar.asp) or if you want to use angular material, it has a directive for [toast messages](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast)

Comment: As i can see in your code, you get back some JSON datas from your PHP script, but, datas are returned in your javascript, and available in the $scope of the view.
If you want to send result datas in another page, you have to play with angular routing and send results as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

One useful option is to use `mysqli_insert_id` to get the last id inserted.
This function get the last id in the DB, not only in the inserted table, but is sufficient.

Another is in manual form, where the query return a custom value.
In your code :

```
$query ="INSERT INTO requests(name, em, telph, dept, det, no, reqdate,answer) 
          VALUES ('$name','$em', '$telph', '$dept', '$det', '$no1','$date1', 'no answer')";

 if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
 {
 $data["message"] = "thank you for your request, your request nymber is: " .$no1;
 }
} 
echo json_encode($data);
```

Add this changes :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO requests(name, em, telph, dept, det, no, reqdate, answer) 
         VALUES ('$name','$em', '$telph', '$dept', '$det', '$no1', '$date1', 'no answer')";
$query .="; select 1 as insert_ok;";

 if($stmt=mysqli_query($connect, $query)) // Get result
 {
     $fetch = mysql_fetch_object($stmt);

        if ($fetch->insert_ok) {
          $data["message"] = "thank you for your request, your request nymber is: " .$no1;
        }else{
            $data["message"] = "The register wasn't inserted";

 } // else
}  //if $stmt
echo json_encode($data);
```

And in your script code: validate the insert_ok value returned from the php script.

Comment: user2505515 thank you for your answer, but i want only display  $data["message"] = "thank you for your request, your request nymber is: " .$no1;
on new page not in same page of inserting data !!!

Comment: Try the end of the answer :   "And in your script code: validate the insert_ok value returned from the php script." In the target page.